# Hash decryption (MD5?)

Tags: hash, md5

So, I've got this Hash:

```
a6086de16e0c4476af46d773cd0342be
```

And I'm not sure what type of Hash it is. I believe it's MD5, but I'm not sure. Anyone able to decrypt this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot "decrypt" a hash function as this would defeat the purpose of hashing something to begin with. Remember, hash functions are **one-way** functions. You are not meant to ever find what produced that hash.

What exactly are you trying to figure out?

Since your output here is 32 characters or 128 bits, it could be an number of hash functions including MD5 as you mentioned. Also, I hope you know that MD5 is no longer considered secure.

Here are some more related answers: [MD4 vs MD5, their differences & why they are not encryption aglorithms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71709/difference-between-md4-and-md5-encryption)